# SQL select one from each group

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume this table,

```
id  name   class
---+-----+------
 1     a    rare 
 2     a  common
 3     b  common 
 4     b  common
```

and we group rows by `name`. How to select from each group the only rare row if exists or else (if rare does not occur in the grouping) the first common row, so that we get

```
id  name   class
---+-----+------
 1     a    rare 
 3     b  common
```

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: mysql, thanks edited tags.

Comment: See here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7fe4/4